# Why does this query return no result

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have simple query in MySQL like

```
SELECT * FROM generals WHERE `Key` =  '{$key}'
```

I want to create function in Oracle using PL/SQL, and when I convert it to `PL/SQL`‚it looks like

```
FUNCTION GET_GENERALS_BY_KEY(p_key IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN rc FOR 
  SELECT * FROM generals WHERE Key LIKE '%p_key%';
RETURN rc;
END GET_GENERALS_BY_KEY;
```

When I test it, I call function like

```
SELECT GENERALS_PACKAGE.GET_GENERALS_BY_KEY('Company_Name') FROM DUAL;
```

But doesn't return anything.
But when I use query like this it return result.

```
SELECT * FROM generals WHERE Key = 'VAT';
```

What is wrong ? Where did I made mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
OPEN rc FOR
SELECT * FROM generals WHERE Key LIKE '%' || p_key || '%';

                                          ^^       ^^
                                          concatenation
```